# How to save mesh coordinate when batch exporting stl files?

Tags: mesh, export, stl

When I Batch export objects of a scene each one into a single stl at the same time, it seems it resets the coordinates of each one.

Is there a way to make it save the coordinates so I can load all the stl files in another software and let the meshes still being in the correct position, and not at the origin?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you apply the location, rotation and scale before saving?

Comment: They can be transformed indipendently. Also, it seems obj file contains all the separated meshes as one file, but stl, if saves alone will join all of them, while batch exported will reset the coordinates. @RonJensen